# Building a function that changes mobile/cell numbers to in internation format +

Tags: function, t-sql

I'm trying to build a function that changes our mobile/cell numbers to the international format.

I've used this, however it only returns the '+' without the rest of the number.

The mobile/cell table is nvachar

```
ALTER FUNCTION [CRM].[fn_FormatTEST](@MobilePhone nvarchar(255)) 

RETURNS nvarchar(255)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @ret nvarchar;

SELECT @ret =               
    CASE 

        WHEN SUBSTRING(@MobilePhone,1,3) <> '+44' THEN STUFF(@MobilePhone,1,1,'+44')

          ELSE MobilePhone
    END
FROM Contacts
WHERE MobilePhone = @MobilePhone;



        RETURN @ret
END;
```

Appreciate any help you guys can give me

Comment: Unless you're using SQl Server 2019, I recommend against Scalar functions, and should stick to inline Table Value Functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not as simple as this?

```
CASE WHEN MobileNumber LIKE '0%' THEN '+44' + STUFF(MobileNumber,1,1,'') ELSE MobileNumber END
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b0505d6125b51b31b88be7b46373c935)
(*Numbers are made up, and any real numbers are by complete coincidence.*)